# app engine loading css and js files

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel

Hello I just have deployed my laravel application in google app engine. But I have problems with css and js loading.
I am changing app.yaml like below:

```
handlers:

- url: /css
  static_dir: public/assets/bootstrap/css
```

But instead of loading css, it just loads css.map files inside public/assets/bootstrap/css

Comment: what url did you hit?

Comment: thts url in header.php {{ HTML::style('assets/css/theme.css') }} I am not sure about the url that you are talking about?

Comment: I tried even this - url: /assets/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|png$))
  static_files: public/assets/\1
  upload: public/assets/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|png$))
  application_readable: true          But it's not working

Comment: Try using: - url: /css
  static_dir: public/assets/bootstrap/css
  mime_type: text/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
- url: /(.+\.(css|js))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(css|js)$
  application_readable: true
```

no need to revise any url.. Hope this helps